# Multiple showDialog for validation

Tags: flutter

On my project I need to use several `showDialog` one after the other.
For user creation, I use a `SearchField` widget to retrieve info from a table related to the user.
If the SearchField value does not exist I would like to propose the creation. Depending on the choice either the form is in error or I propose to register the user.

For this I use a showDialog in the validator of the SearchField and an if validator is correct.
My problem is that my second dialog box is displayed before validating the first one and even above that of the SearchField.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you,

```
class InformationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InformationsPage({
    required Key key,
    required this.user,
    required this.type,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final User user;
  final FenType type;

  @override
  InformationsPageState createState() => InformationsPageState();
}

class InformationsPageState extends State<InformationsPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  InformationsPageState({this.user});
  final User? user;
  late UserApi _api;
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

 
  bool _familyIsCreated = false;

  late User userSaved;
  late FenType type;

  //Info Form
  var _pseudoController = TextEditingController();
  var _familyController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _api = UserApi();
    _pseudoController = TextEditingController(text: widget.user.pseudo);
    _familyController = TextEditingController(text: widget.user.familyName);
    userSaved = User.fromUser();
    type = widget.type;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pseudoController.dispose();
    _familyController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FutureBuilder(
            future: _api.getFamilies(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Family>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                    child: Text(
                        "Something wrong with message: ${snapshot.error.toString()}"));
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                List<Family> _list = snapshot.data!;
                return _buildDropdownSearchFamilies(_list);
              } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }),
        TextFormField(
            readOnly: type == FenType.read ? true : false,
            inputFormatters: [LowerCaseTextFormatter()],
            controller: _pseudoController,
            onSaved: (value) => userSaved.pseudo = value,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              hintText: 'Pseudo',
              labelText: 'Pseudo',
            ),
            validator: (value) =>
                value!.isEmpty ? 'Obligatory' : null),
      ],
    );
  }

  int? _contains(List<Family> list, String? name) {
    int? res = -1;
    for (Family element in list) {
      if (element.name == name) {
        res = element.id;
        break;
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

  Widget _buildDropdownSearchFamilies(List<Family> _list) {
    return SearchField(
        controller: _familyController,
        suggestions: _list
            .map((e) =>
                SearchFieldListItem(e.name!, child: Text(e.name!), item: e.id))
            .toList(),
        hint: 'Family',
        validator: (x) {
          if (x!.isEmpty) {
            userSaved.familyId = null;
            userSaved.familyName = null;
            return null;
          }
          int? id = _contains(_list, x);
          if (id == -1) {
            userSaved.familyId == null;
            showDiaglog(x);
            if (userSaved.familyId != null) {
              return null;
            } else {
              return 'Family not exist';
            }
          } else {
            userSaved.familyId = id;
            userSaved.familyName = x;
            return null;
          }
        },
        searchInputDecoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Family', icon: Icon(Icons.groups)),
        itemHeight: 50,
        onTap: (x) {
          userSaved.familyId = x.item as int?;
          userSaved.familyName = x.child.toString();
        });
  }

  showDiaglog(String family) async {
    String title = "Family";
    String message =
        "Family $family not exist. Create ?";
    String textKoButton = "no";
    String textOkButton = "yes";

    MyDialog alert = MyDialog(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        onPressedKo: koButtonPressed(),
        onPressedOk: okButtonPressed(family),
        textKoButton: textKoButton,
        textOkButton: textOkButton);

    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  void Function() koButtonPressed() => () {
        _familyIsCreated = false;
        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
      };
  void Function() okButtonPressed(family) => () {
        _save(family);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      };

  void _save(family) async {
    UserApi apiUser = UserApi();
    Family oldF = Family.empty();
    Family newF = Family.empty();
    newF.name = family;
    newF.createdAt = oldF.createdAt;
    newF.deletedAt = newF.deletedAt;
    Map<String, dynamic> data = oldF.toJson(newF);
    int res = -1;
    res = await apiUser.createFamily(data);

    SnackBar snackBar;
    if (res != -1) {
      snackBar = MyWidget.okSnackBar('Family created');
      userSaved.familyId = res;
      userSaved.familyName = family;
    } else {
      snackBar = MyWidget.koSnackBar(
          'Family not created');
      userSaved.familyId = null;
      userSaved.familyName = null;
    }
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

My form :

```
class UserFormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/admin/user-form';
  final User? user;
  final FenType fenType;
  const UserFormPage({Key? key, required this.user, required this.fenType})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserFormPageState createState() => _UserFormPageState();
}

class _UserFormPageState extends State<UserFormPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey =
      GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: '_appState');

  static final GlobalKey<InformationsPageState> _infoKey =
      GlobalKey<InformationsPageState>();

  late TabController _controller;
  late User _user;
  late User _userSaved;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _user = widget.user!;
    _userSaved = widget.user!;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () =>
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.admUserList),
        ),
        title: const Text('Member'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
              visible: widget.fenType != FenType.read ? true : false,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    return;
                  }
                  showDiaglog();
                },
              ))
        ],
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: const [
            Tab(text: 'Info'),
            Tab(text: 'Others'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                      child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                            InformationsPage(
                                user: _user,
                                key: _infoKey,
                                type: widget.fenType),
                          ])),
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          DetailsPage(
                              user: _user,
                              key: _detailsKey,
                              type: widget.fenType)
                        ],
                      )),
                    ],
                  ))
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }

  void _save() async {
    final infoState = _infoKey.currentState;
    _userSaved = infoState?.userSaved ?? _user;
    _userSaved.pseudo = infoState?.userSaved.pseudo ?? _user.pseudo;
    Map<String, dynamic> data = _user.userToJsonClean(_userSaved);

    if (!_userSaved.userIsUpdated()) {
      final outSnackBar = MyWidget.okSnackBar('Not update');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(outSnackBar);
    } else {
      UserApi apiUser = UserApi();
      bool res = false;
      res = widget.fenType == FenType.update
          ? await apiUser.update(data)
          : await apiUser.create(data);

      SnackBar snackBar;
      res
          ? snackBar = MyWidget.okSnackBar('Member saved')
          : snackBar = MyWidget.koSnackBar(
              'Member not saved');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      _user = _userSaved;
      if (widget.fenType == FenType.create) {
        Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(Routes.admUserList);
      }
    }
  }

  void showDiaglog() {
    String pseudo = _userSaved.pseudo!;
    String title = "Save";
    String message = widget.fenType == FenType.create
        ? "Create member $pseudo ?"
        : "Save meber $pseudo ?";
    String textKoButton = "no";
    String textOkButton = "yes";

    MyDialog alert = MyDialog(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        onPressedKo: koButtonPressed(),
        onPressedOk: okButtonPressed(),
        textKoButton: textKoButton,
        textOkButton: textOkButton);

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  void Function() koButtonPressed() => () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
      };
  void Function() okButtonPressed() => () {
        _formKey.currentState!.save();
        _save();
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      };
}
```

Comment: Can you share any code sample to find out where's the problem?

Comment: I update my questions with my code. Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem to modified the widget `SearchField` to a `DropdownSearch`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).